# Proof limit is 1

Tags: calculus, limits

We have a limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\log(n)}(n^{1/n}-1)$$

Can someone give me a hint. I tired using $e-\log$ trick but was a bit stuck

$$\frac{n}{\log(n)}(n^{1/n}-1)=\frac{n}{\log(n)}(e^{\log(n)/n}-1)$$

Comment: Hint: the you know the derivative of $e^x$, so in particular you know the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}(e^h-1)/h$.

Comment: what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{log(n)}{n}$?

Comment: Expand $e^{(\log n)/n}. $

Comment: @psl2Z $\lim_{n->\infty }log(n)/n$ is 0? and $n^{1/n} is 1$ but can we split them up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n}{\log(n)}(e^{\log(n)/n}-1) = \frac{n}{\log(n)}\left(-1+1 + \frac{\log n}{n} + \frac{\left( \frac{\log n}{n} \right)^2}{2!} + \ldots \right) $$

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you

Comment: You're welcome. That wasn't super easy though: I had to use Tomy's comment from the comments... Also, yay! Now my reputation is at exactly $10, 000.$ Thanks lol

Comment: it can be done easier

Comment: @psI2Z I'm sure it can, but this answer is hardly "difficult"...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes it needs more reflection to get what you did. Nice! But strange for me that the OP leaves the easier one!!! :)))

Comment: I couldn't figure the other answer out on my own for some reason. That's poor from me...

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{n}=0$ so we get: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\operatorname{log}(n)/n} - 1}{ \frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{n}} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h} = (e^{x})'(0) = 1$$